# uninstall yoast plugin after using it in website

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using Yoast plugin in my WordPress website for SEO. If I uninstall it after implementing SEO, will its features be removed from my website? Features like title, meta descriptions etc. I want to uninstall to make my website faster to load.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those features wil be removed (or rather: not be present anymore): They are added dynamically by the plugin when a page is loaded. So if the plugin is gone, that won't happen anymore.

If your website is static, you could copy the relevant HTML meta tags for SEO from the header while the plugin is active, insert them in your code (i.e. in the `header.php` file) and then deactivate the plugin. But you'd have to do that for every page seperately (which works against the concept of having *one*  `header.php` file for all pages). But all that is rather mere theory for a Wordpress site (I wouldn't bother trying that).

Answer (score 0):

First be sure that it is the Yoast plugin that is making your website slow.

- You can do this by deactivating all plugin then activating one by one until you find the plugin causing the problem.
- You can also view ways to make your website faster using this guide: 
  [The Ultimate Guide to Boost WordPress Speed & Performance](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wordpress-performance-speed/)

Deactivating Yoast SEO would remove all optimization done on the site as they are all loaded dynamically on page load.